# How is Boolean Algebra efficient in practise?

Tags: optimization, boolean-logic, circuit, boolean-algebra

Thanks for taking the time, just as a note, l understand the basics of Boolean Algebra.

Although l understand how Boolean Algebra is a useful optimization technique in very small circuits, surely it would take far too long in a realistically-sized circuit(s). Are circuits isolated down and have the laws of Boolean Algebra applied to them, which would take a long time, or is there a better technique than Boolean Algebra used to optimize more complex circuits? I just got really curious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think its efficiency wouldn't scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is efficient.

We automate it now. It's called [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog).

The idea is the chip designer writes this code that looks very close to Pascal, and the Verilog compiler, and get the chip circuit layout on the other side.

Yeah so a human is a little better at circuit layout. With millions and millions of gates that doesn't matter because the human won't get it done in time.

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer. Somehow l didn't think of circuits being automated haha, so are big circuits in modern computers optimized through an automatic process such as Verilog?

Comment: @ARobertC: I don't actually know if Intel uses Verilog or if they've got something more powerful. I know lots of companies laying out microprocessors use Verilog.

Comment: That's really interesting, I'll have to look more into that, thanks a lot!